# Replace Code of TFS project in a server from a different Server

Tags: tfs-2015

our team has migrated TFS projects to a new TFS server but few members of the team are committing code to old TFS server unknowingly. How do we migrate the code (Pull Requests, Branches)on the old TFS server and just replace the code part on the Target Server. Because, there are other items like user stories, TFS tickets valid on new server as users creating them.
Do we need to take down TFS server and will it affect other projects in collection.
I cannot find a straight forward way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find a straightforward way because **there isn't one**. The amount of effort that would be involved in re-synchronizing the two instances would be absolutely massive and would require the setup and usage of various third-party utilities.

Source code is easy enough to address on a person-by-person basis (have them update their remotes to point to the new server and push there instead). Pull requests? No way to migrate. Work items? Possible but a huge pain. Other stuff? Who knows.

Your best bet here is to cut your losses.